# Azure AD AcquireToken does not work with app password

Tags: c#, azure, azure-active-directory

I'm trying to verify a user's password in Azure AD using the .NET ADAL library.
This works fine for a regular user account without MFA, but I ran into problems doing this for a user who has MFA activated.

When using the user's actual password, I got `AADSTS50076: Application password is required.`, which is fair enough, but when I then created a new app password, I received the error `AADSTS70002: Error validating credentials. AADSTS50020: Invalid username or password`. I've created multiple app passwords but they all do not work.

The code used to attempt authentication is as follows:

```cs
var ac = new AuthenticationContext("https://login.windows.net/my-tenant.com");
var authResult = ac.AcquireToken("https://graph.windows.net", "my-client-id", new UserCredential("my.account@my-tenant.com", "my-password"));
```

The user that is trying to authenticate is a Global Admin in this AD.

Is it even possible to do authentication like this for a user with MFA?

Comment: This is not possible because of the user interaction required for MFA.

Comment: Isn't that what the app passwords are for, to be able to log into things that one cannot log into with MFA? I've created those for logging into Office 365 on my smartphone/Outlook for example. Also, the error message explicitly says I should create an app password to authenticate.

Comment: Yes, and as you pointed out in your question it works fine for a user not configured for MFA.

Comment: Of course; a user without MFA can't and doesn't need to create app passwords, as they can just use their regular password to login. What I'm trying to say is, the error message makes it look like it would be possible to login using an app password. Logging in with an app password works fine in other places. Those two facts combined lead me to think that it should work here too.

Comment: If this was a new user you were likely being prompted to create the new password just as you would if you were trying to sign-in as the user for the first time.

Comment: Both users are existing users, which already went through the password changing process after initial login.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, to answer my own question somewhat, I resorted to doing the following (cleaned up for brevity):

```
public class AzureAdAuthenticationProvider
{
    private const string AppPasswordRequiredErrorCode = "50076";
    private const string AuthorityFormatString = "https://login.windows.net/{0}";
    private const string GraphResource = "https://graph.windows.net";

    private AuthenticationContext _authContext;
    private string _clientId;

    public AzureAdAuthenticationProvider()
    {
        var tenantId = "..."; // Get from configuration

        _authContext = new AuthenticationContext(string.Format(AuthorityFormatString, tenantId));
    }

    public bool Authenticate(string user, string pass)
    {
        try
        {
            _authContext.AcquireToken(GraphResource, _clientId, new UserCredential(user, pass));

            return true;
        }
        catch (AdalServiceException ase)
        {
            return ase.ServiceErrorCodes.All(sec => sec == AppPasswordRequiredErrorCode);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return false; // Probably needs proper handling
        }
    }
}
```

It's not pretty, but it does the job.

By using `ServiceErrorCodes.All()`, I ensure that only when a single AppPasswordRequired error occurs, authentication has succeeded.

The only disadvantage to this method, is that a user with MFA enabled has to use their actual account password to login. Using an app password does not seem to be supported.

Comment: I would love to be able to reproduce this. How does this class hook in with the canned Startup class? Also, where is IAuthenticationProvider defined (is it just yours for IoC)?

Comment: I've no idea; I haven't used this in conjunction with the Startup class. IAuthenticationProvider is mine, removed it for clarity.