# Login fault for Azure AD

Tags: .net, azure, azure-active-directory

I attempt to add a login system by azure AD to my .NET Web app project,

I have referenced the code in the reply of this,

[Azure AD AcquireToken does not work with app password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29366984/azure-ad-acquiretoken-does-not-work-with-app-password)

This is part of my code:

```
if (Page.Request.Params.AllKeys.Contains("UserName") && Page.Request.Params.AllKeys.Contains("Password"))
{
    string username = Page.Request.Params["UserName"];
    string password = Page.Request.Params["Password"];
    string AppPasswordRequiredErrorCode = "50076";
    string AuthorityFormatString = "https://login.windows.net/{0}";
    string GraphResource = "https://graph.windows.net";
    string tenantId = "xxxxx.onmicrosoft.com";
    string _clientId = "........";
    AuthenticationContext _authContext = new AuthenticationContext(string.Format(AuthorityFormatString, tenantId));

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(username) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(password))
    {
        try
        {
            AuthenticationResult result = _authContext.AcquireToken(GraphResource, _clientId, new UserCredential(username, password)); 
        }                    
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Helper.WriteExceptionContent(Page.Response, ex.Message);
        }
}
```

I have set up a user in the azure ad for testing, with username: test1@xxxxx.onmicrosoft.com and password generated by "reset password" button

I am sure I have input correct username and password while testing, however an exception is thrown:

> AADSTS70002: Error validating credentials. AADSTS50055: Password is expired.
>
> Trace ID: ....... Correlation ID: .......Timestamp: 2015-09-14 08:35:59Z

So, what is the solution to resolve this problem?

Is it caused by the temp password? Or other factors?

Answer (score 2):

You need to reset the password for the user to a permanent password after resetting it.  An easy way to do this is to open a browser to https://myapps.microsoft.com (Access Panel) and sign-in as the user using the *temporary password*.  You will be prompted to enter a new *permanent password* for the user.  Click the button to update the password and sign in.

[image]

After you do this, your call to AcquireToken should work.